# MSP432+BLE+ Debugger interfacing

Tags: microcontroller, uart, embedded, msp430, bluetooth-low-energy

I would like to Interface a BLE to a MSP432 microcontroller in serial. The BLE has a inbulit Atmel controller. I have a firmware for BLE in keil. Intially I have flashed the firmware to BLE directly from a debugger and worked on the BLE. Now I should have a MSP432 in btween debugger and BLE.

I should flash the BLE via MSP432 in serial. I am planning to connect the hardware as below image. Is this way work out?.
My another important question is I have to write the firmware for MSP432 and then combne the BLE code in to the MSP432 code?.

If so How can I send the perticuler BLE portion of code to the BLE?.

If I dont connect the seial pins of debugger to MSP432 how can I see the serial data on terminal in PC?.

[image]

Comment: what is your BLE brand/model/reference?

Comment: what do you want to program into your MSP432? just a bootloader?

Comment: do you need to make any changes on your BLE or did you make all the changes needed for the firmware to be operationnal?

Comment: what is the communication protocol between the BLE and the MSP432? AT-Commands?

Answer (score 0):

**Q1**

The most simple method: after the firmware for the BLE-µC is created, convert the binary data to C-Array. Include this C-Array into your MSP432-firmware. Now you can transfer the BLE-firmware easily, as it is available as static resource.

The only limitation is the amount of storage available on your MSP-µC, it's firmware and the BLE-firmware both need to fit on the MSP433 flash.

**Q2**

By looking at the technical reference manual of your BLE-µC. The firmware-upgrade procedure is not very complex and Atmel's manuals are sufficiently detailed.

**Q3**

> If I don't connect the serial pins of debugger to MSP432 how can I see
>   the serial data on terminal in PC?.

You will need to find another interface to connect to your computer. UART is not a bus: you cannot connect more than 2 devices over the same wiring.
Maybe your MSP432 has another set of UART-pins that you can use?

Or you could use Bluetooth, you just happen to have a BLE device in your design anyway.

Another possibility would be to pipe the UART-data over the SWD-connection of your debugger. This would at least work during development.